# How do I get Docusign to recognize CSS styling on my document

Tags: docusignapi

I'm very new to docusign. I have an HTML document that is being sent to docusign for signing. It has many dynamic pieces of data and whole sections that need to be displayed/hidden. I am successfully sending this to docusign as a base64 encoded string and am able to get signatures/dates/initials. My goal is to not have to maintain two versions of this document just to make the docusign process work.

I am running into an issue with formatting though. I have CSS in my document that controls how everything is displayed. I make extensive use of flexboxes for my div elements along with inline-block display. Docusign seems to ignore this. It seems to recognize some inline styling but not much. As a result the document is displayed poorly. I can seem to use tables to format things but I'm trying to avoid that. Is there a way to get docusign to understand my stylesheet?

Editing in an example of my css that is not working.

```
.business_information>div:nth-child(-n+5) {
    display: inline-block;
}
.business_information>div {
    padding: 5px; 
}
.signatures {
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
.signature>div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.signatureLine{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color: transparent;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.signatureLabel {
    min-width: 100px;
}
.spacing {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.flexlayout {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flexlayout> * {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

Comment: How does your document differ from the [documented css support](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/click101/customize-elastic-template-appearance/)?

Comment: @stdunbar Sorry I'm not using the Click API, I'm using the eSignature REST API. Like I said I'm very new but I haven't found any references to styles or CSS in the eSignature REST API reference. The examples that I've been able to find are very simple html documents that have very limited styling, at most things like text size/color. My document is not simple and has quite a lot of CSS to control how elements are positioned (in order to avoid a table controlled layout). I'll edit in some CSS from my document as an example to my question

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign handles html docs in either of two ways.

In both cases, only inline CSS is supported.
Images **can** be included by using [image data urls](https://www.google.com/search?q=image+data+url+generator).

### HTML docs converted to PDF

The HTML doc is sent in the [documentBase64](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_documents_documentbase64) attribute. This feature is available with all product plans

### HTML for Responsive Signing / Smart Sections

This feature is an option for DocuSign accounts. It enables you to include the field specifications (tabs) within the HTML. More importantly, you can specify sections in your HTML that will be presented as an accordian to the signer.

Here's a [live example](https://codepen.io/docusign/full/zYmxGdr) of an HTML document using the smart sections feature. [Documentation on smart sections](https://www.google.com/search?q=docusign+developer+html+smart+sections)

```
Since I referenced a codepen example, StackOverflow
requires some "code"
Here is where the smart sections HTML is set in the
envelope object:

            documents: [
                {
                    name: "Business Credit Card Approval.html",
                    documentId: "1",
                    htmlDefinition: {
                        source: htmlDoc,
                        ....
```